# If statement in my Django template...Is there a better way?

Tags: django, django-templates

In my Django template: I'm trying to add an extra div around my for loop only if the length of the data being passed to the template is 3. This is what I'm trying right now but it seems like there could be better way than doing two if statements to check for the length:

```
  {% if items|length == 3 %}
    <div class='three-item-wrap'>
  {% endif %}

      {% for item in items %}
        .......
      {% endfor %}

  {% if items|length == 3 %}
    </div> //close .three-item-wrap
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Better to apply condition on `class` attribute rather than `div` tag i.e `<div class="{% if items|length == 3 %} three-item-wrap {%endif%}">`

Answer (score 0):

you can try like that

```
{% if items|length == 3 %}
    <div class='three-item-wrap'>


      {% for item in items %}
        .......
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  {% else %}
    #another logic goes here
  {% endif %}
```

if you want know more refer the docs [django if tempalate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#if)

Answer (score 0):

I think better way would be to make single if statement check. Just like this:

```
{% if items|length == 3 %}
  <div class='three-item-wrap'>
    {% for item in items %}
       .......
    {% endfor %}
  </div> 
{% else %}
  {% for item in items %}
    .......
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

This way is better because of Django render engine, which firstly check `if` statements and then do `for` loop.
And if something crash in your code, `div` will be without closing tag `</div>`.
 Instead in my code there is no option for div to be without closing tag.

Comment: Why is it better for Django render engine? How would something "crash"? How comes if something "crashes" django will continue rendering the template? Why does it guarantee a closing div? That doesn't make sense at all.